# How to reset values inside DragTarget?

Tags: flutter

I've 2 rows rendered using `Draggable` and `DragTarget`. First row contains jumbled letters of a word and other row contains correct order of the word after dragging corresponding letters from first row, as below:

[image]

Now if I tap on button that jumbles the letters again, I want to reset the data in second row (green container) to `?`, so that user can again drag and drop, but currently I am not sure how to reset the data. Below is the code that generates jumbled letters in first row upon button tap:

```
RaisedButton(
                    color: Colors.redAccent,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _generateJumble(textInput);
                        _controller.clear();
                      });

                    },
                    child: Text('Jumble'),
                  ),
```

...

```
List<String> _generateJumble(String input) {
    inputList = input.split('');
    inputList = inputList.toList()..shuffle();
    outputList = input.split('');

    return inputList;
  }
```

Then the `inputList` and `outputList` is fed to `Draggable` and `DragTarget` respectively to generate the letters.

```
Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: inputList.map((i) {
              return Draggable<String>(
                data: i,
                feedback: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    width: 50,
                    height: 50,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                    child: Text(i.toUpperCase(),
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center)),
                child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    width: 50,
                    height: 50,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                    ),
                    child: Text(i.toUpperCase(),
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center)),
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
          Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: outputList.map((o) {

                  return DragTarget<String>(

                      builder: (BuildContext context,
                          List<String> candidateData,
                          List<dynamic> rejectedData) {

                        if (acceptData == false && candidateData.isEmpty) {
                          return Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              width: 50,
                              height: 50,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.blue,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                              ),
                              child: Text('?',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center));
                        } else {
                          return Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              width: 50,
                              height: 50,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.green,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                              ),
                              child: Text(o.toUpperCase(),
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center));
                        }
                      },
                      onWillAccept: (data) {
                        if (data == o) {
                          acceptData = true;
                          return true;
                        } else {
                          acceptData = false;
                          return false;
                        }
                      },
                      onAccept: (data) {
                        return true;
                      },
                      onLeave: (data) {});
                }).toList()
              )),
```

How do I reset the values in `green containers` to `?` if user taps on the button again ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `RaisedButton` I think all you need to do is set `acceptData` back to false I would also make sure `canidateData` is empty but you don't do anything with `canidateData` in the code you have given us.

```
 RaisedButton(
              color: Colors.redAccent,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  acceptData = false;
                  //canidateData = []; 
                  _generateJumble(textInput);
                  _controller.clear();
                });
              },
              child: Text('Jumble'),
            )
```

Comment: no problem upvote if you found this useful i did the same for you question